# Coherence theorem for symmetric monoidal categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

What's the formal statement for the coherence theorem for symmetric monoidal categories?

I've seen there's some notion of permutation around, but I can't get my head around the thing that "all diagrams commute".

If two verticies of the diagram are different instances of objects, then any two paths define the same permutation? The permutation thing is just in case there are repeated objects? (as in A*A*C vs. A*B*C)

Comment: Have you looked in Chapter XI of the second edition of CWM?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found it clear enough. I took a look also at Natural associativity and commutativity by Mac Lane, but I am not sure about the permutation thing, as any diagram I write (and it seems obvious) ends up having the same permutation from both paths... the only diagrams I find that might not commute are if they have multiple copies of the same object, such as the two maps $A*A*C \to A*A*C$ given by $id$ and $\gamma_{AA} * id$

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct. You need to give different labels to all the objects.

Comment: So, every diagram commutes if the objects in the vertices's expressions are all different (except the unit object)?

Comment: Something like that. The formal statement is in Mac Lane's book.